# MembershipProvider in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, asp.net-membership

How can I add the MembershipProvider class to my .NET 4.0 project in VS 2010 B2?

I want to customize a MembershipProvider, but I cannot without adding this class. Please guide me through this process.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Interesting. However, build errors are your friend ;)

Attempting to build a class library built as you describe, I get the following build error:

> The type name 'MembershipProvider' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

Following the instructions (adding a reference to System.Web.ApplicationServices) allows me to carry on as expected.

Comment: MembershipProvider don't exist in VisualStudio 2010! Can you do it?

Comment: This is also needed when upgrading a project where membership provider is being used.

Answer (score 15):

The MembershipProvider abstract class is part of the System.Web.ApplicationServices namespace in the .net 4.0 Framework. Add a reference to that assembly and it should solve the issue.

Comment: Confirming `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` exists in `System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll`. This isn't confusing at all! =0 Kudos for the help Manthan.

Answer (score 0):

There is an reference not set oder an missing using
namespace is System.Web.Security
Check if assembly System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll is referenced

for more info [checkt out MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Andreas for attention.
i set refrence to System.Web.Security namespace but i can't inherit my Class from MembershipProvider.

Comment: what compiler message do you recive?

Comment: You should post some sample code as the MembershipProvider class is abstract and must be inherited from so I assume you may be going wrong somewhere else?

Comment: I do these steps:

•Create a Class Library project
•Added System.Web refrence to project
•Added a class to project. this class renamed to "SIAMembershipProvider.cs"
•Added "using System.Web.Security;" to top of the class
•Added this code:

namespace SIA.Asp.Net.Membership 
{ 
public class SIAMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider 
{

}
}

Comment: Did you override all Methodes in den class?

Answer (score 0):

On my case, I am using Visual Studio 2019, I need to add both of these:

```
System.Web.ApplicationServices
```

and

```
System.Configuration
```

In order to build it successfully upon inheriting `MembershipProvider` to create my own MyMembershipProvider class.